# Using 2 variables in css variable assignment EOF error

Tags: javascript, variables, escaping, expression

```
root.style.setProperty('--services-box-delay-"+ i +"', totalServicesLines + "s");
```

This is seemingly so simple, but I can’t get it to work due to (probably) variable escaping wrong understanding.

I have two variables here: *i* and *totalServicesLines*.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this and I think it will work:

```
root.style.setProperty('--services-box-delay-"'+ i +'"', totalServicesLines + "s");
```

Example:
If i = 1 and totalServicesLines = 3
With your code, you will get `root.style.setProperty('--services-box-delay-"i"', "3s");`
The variable i will not be evaluated.

Instead, if you add " before and after i, it will be like this:
`root.style.setProperty('--services-box-delay-1', "3s");`.

And these are js and not css variables.

The css property that you're trying to chabge is **--services-box-delay-"1"** which will get "3s" as value.

Comment: Thanks! However, not really. Result is: --services-box-delay-"2": 8s; instead of --services-box-delay-2: 8s;

Comment: Ah yes thank you i have changed the response

Answer (score 0):

Looks weird, but on base of what Mohammed suggested this one works:

```
root.style.setProperty('--services-box-delay-'+ i +'', totalServicesLines + "s");
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot to add "